# problem with reading a file after copy file using os.popen - Python

Tags: python, file

I was trying to copy a file with the command `os.popen('copy source.text desti.text')`
But after that when I'm trying to open it for reading  .. I'm getting an error that the file doesn't even exist.. `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

but I checked it out.. and the file was created ...
What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: And what is your file open command?

Comment: windows10. can you read my response below?

Comment: @user13602281 Hey.. Could you get to solve this? I also am facing the same issue and unable to solve it using "os.popen()"

Answer (score 0):

Your making a call to the OS so, we might need a bit more info.

But, generally, check out https://www.techbeamers.com/python-copy-file/ for some OS agnostic options for file copying in python.

Comment: time_stamp_file_path = "C:\\Users\\"+user+"\\Documents\\Notifications\\time_stamp\\time_stamp.text"

copy_time_stamp_file_path = "C:\\Users\\"+user+"\\Documents\\Notifications\\sorted_time_stamp\\copy_time_stamp.text"

os.popen('copy '+time_stamp_file_path+' '+copy_time_stamp_file_path)

Comment: My experience of popen on Windows is none, sorry. Can you try the shutil methods in the link I posted?

Comment: The other gotcha I was thinking you might fall afoul of is that the relative path to the file, from the open command, is different to that from the copy command. But, you’re using full file paths in the copy command; I assume you’re doing likewise in the open command?